# .NET Roles, Membership, FormsAuthentication, MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, authorization, membership, roles

I am creating a web application using MVC3. I have one database which contains all of the tables I use in the application (including a Users and Roles table, which are the focus of this question).

I have already set it up (very quickly) to Authenticate the user using SetAuthCookie. However as my application has different roles, I also need to be able to find out if the user is in a specific role before they can access specific controllers.

I have spent the last few days trying and failing to implement various solutions from here and general online searches. Topics of discussion have been FormsAuthentication, IIdentity, IPrincipal, MembershipProvider, RoleProvider. And after several failed attempts I am completely confused by everything.

In the past I have used the default accounts stuff using the ASPNET Membership DB, and since I didn't have to touch it at all, had no problems. But I would prefer all of my tables were in the same DB this time around. I would also prefer that I can decorate the controllers with [Authorize], [Role="Sysadmin"] etc.

I am aware that this and similar questions are asked a lot and that there are several resources available which cover the topics described above, but the problem is that the solutions are conflicting, or assume knowledge of other related fields, or the presence of non-standard classes, and even in some cases provide a flawed solution "for simplicity's sake".

So to recap:

- I have a blank MVC3 project.
- I have a Database with my Users Table and Roles Table (each user can have one role).
- I want to decorate the controllers with [Authorize], [Role="Sysadmin"]
- I do not care how complex the solution is. I am willing to spend as much time as necessary to get the most secure and efficient solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom membership providers, here is a link that explains more:
[MVC 3 Customer Membership providers](http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/)